# Jordan inner measure of closure and Jordan outer measure of interior

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a bounded set.
I know that $\overline{m}^J(E)=\overline{m}^J(\bar{E})$ and $\underline{m}^J(E)=\underline{m}^J(E^°)$, so it's always $\underline{m}^J(E^°)\leq \overline{m}^J(\bar{E})$.
Is it also true that: $\overline{m}^J(E^°)\leq \underline{m}^J(\bar{E})$?
Taking $E=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0 ; 1]$ it seems so, but I don't know if it's true for every $E$.